# io.on is not working while making connection using socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, websocket, socket.io

I am facing a problem (very frustrated), while I am connecting the io.on function. I am following a youtube tutorial(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QNBVG2yqKA), where a chat application is made using node js and socket io. The code in the tutorial and mine are matching exactly same(checked 100 times), but mine code is not working.

#### Server-side code

```
//Node server
const io=require('socket.io')(3000);

const users={};
io.on('connection', socket=>{
    console.log("hi");
    socket.on("new-user-joined",name=>{
        console.log("name",name);
        users[socket.id]=name;
        socket.broadcast.emit("user-joined",name);
    });
    socket.on("send",message=>{
        socket.broadcast.emit("receive",{message: message, name:users[socket.id]});
    });
});
```

#### CLIENT Side Code

```
const socket=io.connect("http://localhost:3000");
const form=document.getElementById("sendContainer");
const msg=document.getElementById("messageInp");
const msgContainer=document.querySelector(".container");

const append=(message,position)=>{
    const messageEle=document.createElement("div");
    messageEle.innerText=message;
    messageEle.classList.add("message");
    messageEle.classList.add(position);
    msgContainer.append(messageEle);
}

const name1=prompt("Enter your name to join");
socket.emit("new-user-joined", name1);

socket.on("user-joined", name=>{
    append(`${name} joined the chat`, "right");
})
```

server side code is not running beyond const users={} object, I tested using console log

and in the browser console this error is displaying

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75CSn.png)

Please Help me solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the cors object while initiating the socket in which you should add origins, otherwise it blocks the request.

```
cors: {
    origins: [],
  },
```

You can check the socket docs here for handling cors :https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/